# decode signedcms in node.js

Tags: c#, node.js

I'm trying to port some C# code to Node.js. I have a signed CMS message. I need to access the contents of the encoded message. I've tried searching around, [node-forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) seems like it should do what I want, but I'm having a hard time navigating the API.

```cs
var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
var message = new System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms();
message.Decode(file);
var content = message.ContentInfo.Content;
// use content...
```

What would be the equivalent of the above code in Node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this library](https://github.com/lapo-luchini/extractCMS), which can parse the signed CMS message. The C# code turns into this JS code:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const CMS = require('@lapo/extractcms');

const file = fs.readFileSync(path);
const content = CMS.extract(file);
// use content...
```